# Python flask application throws the following error on start TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: ubuntu, flask, python-3.9

I have a flask app that throws the following error when I try to start it:

```
$ flask -A myapp run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/bin/flask", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1063, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1651, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1698, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 565, in get_command
    self._load_plugin_commands()
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 559, in _load_plugin_commands
    for ep in metadata.entry_points(group="flask.commands"):
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 934, in entry_points
    return EntryPoints(eps).select(**params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 931, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/_py39compat.py", line 18, in normalized_name
    return dist._normalized_name
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 856, in _normalized_name
    or super()._normalized_name
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 474, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 774, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
  File "/home/ubuntu/micromamba/envs/argopy-tests/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have the same error if I try to check the routes.
I feel this is due to the environment and not the app, any idea ?